# Fraction with difference of two cube root.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> Simplify : $$\frac{x-y}{x^{\frac 1 3} - y^{\frac 1 3}}$$

Attempt:
By expanding the denominator, you will get $(x-y)\left(x ^\left.\frac23\right.+ x^\left.\frac13\right.y^\left.\frac13\right. + y ^\left.\frac23\right.\right)$. Then dividing the numerator with the denominator you will get $$\frac{1}{x^{\frac 2 3}+x^{\frac 1 3}y^{\frac 1 3} + y^{\frac 2 3}}$$
This is the answer I got.

But the answer from the textbook where I got the question is: $$x ^\left.\frac23\right.+ x^\left.\frac13\right.y^\left.\frac13\right. + y ^\left.\frac23\right.$$

Comment: Can you show how you arrived at this answer?

Comment: @Taylor Rendon,  sorry for the wrong question,  I have edited the question correctly.

Comment: But the answer from the textbook  where I got the question was thus:  $$(x ^\left.\frac23\right.+ x^\left.\frac13\right.y^\left.\frac13\right. + y ^\left.\frac23\right.)$$

Comment: By expanding the denominator, you will get.         $(x-y)(x ^\left.\frac23\right.+ x^\left.\frac13\right.y^\left.\frac13\right. + y ^\left.\frac23\right.)$     then dividing the numerator with the denominator you will get.            $$frac{1/(x ^\left.\frac23\right.+ x^\left.\frac13\right.y^\left.\frac13\right. + y ^\left.\frac23\right.)}$$

Comment: @Michael, can you tell what identity you're using?

Comment: @UmbQbify -Key20, sorry for any inconvenience for not have written the question as required in this platform. I am new here and equally am trying to be familiar with the platform....... Also I am glad to the person that answered my question. I am happy now.  I fully understand the step towards how the answer was gotten. Thanks once more. 

Comment: @Michael, I'm not talking about that.. but yeah, it is not upto community guidelines (but that's a common scene anyway). The answer explains the hint I was trying to give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $x^{1/3}=s$ and $y^{1/3}=t$. Then \begin{align} \frac{x-y}{x^{1/3} - y^{1/3}} &= \frac{s^3-t^3}{s-t}=\frac{(s-t)(s^2+st+t^2)}{s-t}=s^2+st+t^2 \end{align}

as in your textbook.

Here is an error in your argument.

> By expanding the denominator, you will get $(x-y)(x
>  ^\left.\frac23\right.+ x^\left.\frac13\right.y^\left.\frac13\right. +
>  y ^\left.\frac23\right.)$

The denominator in the problem is $x^{1/3}-y^{1/3}=s-t$, which does not equal to $$(x-y)(x
^\left.\frac23\right.+ x^\left.\frac13\right.y^\left.\frac13\right. + y ^\left.\frac23\right.)=(s^3-t^3)(s^2+st+t^2) = s^5+s^4t+s^3t^2-s^2t^3-st^4-t^5$$ in general.

Comment: please can you explain  more how you expanded this $${x^{1/3} - y^{1/3}}$$ .... And how you got $${(s^3-t^3)(s^2+st+t^2)}$$ especially how come about ${(s^3-t^3)}$ as one of the factor in the expansion and not ${(s-t)}$

Comment: @Michael, the identity $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)$. Author used $x^{\frac13} =s$ for simplicity's sake. Cube both sides. Same for y and t

Comment: @Michael  I'm not sure I understand your request. From your comment, it seems that you calculated wrongly that $$x^{1/3} - y^{1/3} = (x-y)(x^{2/3} + x^{1/3}y^{1/3}+y^{2/3})$$ which leads to $$ \frac{x-y}{x^{1/3} - y^{1/3}} = \frac{1}{x^{2/3}+x^{1/3}y^{1/3}+y^{2/3}}$$ I intended to say this is not the case, by showing that $$x^{1/3} - y^{1/3} = s-t \neq  (s^3 - t^3)(s^2+st+t^2) =(x-y)(x^{2/3} + x^{1/3}y^{1/3}+y^{2/3}) $$

Comment: @sera,  in general what you are saying is that $x^{1/3}$ - $y^{1/3}$ is the inverse of ${x^3-y^3}$.

Comment: @Michael, No. Definitely not. Why would you think that? $x^{1/3}-y^{1/3}\ne \frac{1}{x^3-y^3}$

Comment: @umbQbify -key20,  for clarity sake then expand  the identity ${x^{1/3} - y^{1/3}}$ solely for me.

Comment: @Michael , there is no such identity! (In basic algebra)

Comment: @ sera, please can you still help out,  by solely expanding the identity in this context. ${x^{1/3} - y^{1/3}}$. ....Also if it pleases you, I would like to have your mobile/phone number. Thank you in advance in getting your reply soon.